# Mask-RCNN deployment on Web application

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

Currently attempting to create a Web Application to detect flowers. I have done the training codes using Mask-RCNN on google colab and would like to enquire how to go about delivering onto the web. I have attempted to search but most required to build my own API and was wondering if there was an alternate method to go about ( for example somehow using tensorflow.js). If there isnt how to get start on the API.

Comment: Transfer learning image classifier In this tutorial, you will learn how to build a custom image classifier that you will train on the fly in the browser using TensorFlow.js. For more information about the tutorial visit https://www.tensorflow.org/js/tutorials/transfer/image_classification